# hide other apps from my app: objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, hide

I have an app that downloads pdf documents and I have used UIDocumentInteractionController to give the user the option of opening them in other apps. I however have one app that I don't want the user to be able to view in the "Open In" list. That app is called NotCoolApp. Is there a way I can list the names of apps that I don't want my app to see, plist maybe?

Comment: Just curious, what would your app do with it if it is known?

Comment: Since you're curious here is the real situation: i'm making a dropbox app, and it initially has to get permission from the user to access their account. What the dropbox api/sdk does is that if the user already has the dropbox app it opens it up and says myApp wants to access my dropbox. clicking yes redirects back to my app. If user does not have the dropbox app installed a small window pops up from within my app asking user to enter their username and password and then asks them to allow access. I only want this window whether the dropbox app is present or not. Redirection is not so neat